# Using Selenium to login to Gmail/save cookies and then use requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to sign into Gmail using Selenium and then using requests (or aiohttp) to do Google searches.

Before all this, I was using pure Selenium to log in and do searches, watch YouTube etc. However recently I began to ask if I could use pure requests to sign into Gmail. I was told that was extremely hard due to a large amount of JavaScript being used. So I thought of a new way (using Selenium to log in and then proceed to use requests) and wanted to see if it would work.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")
email_phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")
email_phone.send_keys("your_emailid_phone")
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
password.send_keys("your_password")
driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.get("https://google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))



session = requests.session()
with open('cookies.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f))
    session.get("https://youtube.com")
```

There are no errors when running this code. However, I was concerned about whether this approach will work. If I load the cookies that were there when I signed into Gmail (using Selenium) will any activity I do reflect on my Gmail (my intention).

Comment: So, what you want to do actually?

Comment: Why not use this? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Comment: @RatmirAsanov what I am trying to do is login to Gmail (using Selenium), save the cookies that are there when I am logged into Gmail, and then proceed to use those cookies in requests to search google,watch youtube etc. The point is to minimize the amount of Selenium possible.

Comment: @kcorlidy I can use that API, but from what I read in the description  its basically like selenium in the sense that it creates a new browser session etc. I am much more familiar with selenium than Google's API hence my choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist using `selenium`, so you should know

1. `password` should not be `WebDriverWait(driver, ...`. `WebDriverWait(driver, ...` will return nothing useful for you in this case. Also it raises error when it can't find specific element in time limit.
2. You have to save cookie and expiry together, so you can get new one again when you really need it
3. Be careful the issue of domain. In your case you access Google main site finally, which means if you use `driver.get_cookies()` after that, you can not get the cookies which belong to `https://myaccount.google.com/`

Full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pickle

def save_cookies():
    email = "@gmail.com"
    password = ""

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")
    email_phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")
    email_phone.send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    password.send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    google_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    cookies = ({cookie.get("name"):cookie.get("value") for cookie in google_cookies}, google_cookies[0].get("expiry"))

    with open("cookies.pkl","wb") as fd:
        pickle.dump(cookies, fd)

    return cookies


import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    with open("cookies.pkl","rb") as fd:
        cookies, expiry = pickle.load(fd)
        if expiry < time.time():
            cookies, expiry = save_cookies()
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Referer": "https://www.google.com/",
        "Accept-Encoding": "deflate",
        "Accept-Language": "en;q=0.6",
        }

    resp = s.get("https://myaccount.google.com/"
        ,headers=headers,cookies=cookies)
    print(resp.url)
```